# Error trying to run Selenium with IE 8

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium, cucumber

I am getting the following error:

Unable to find standalone executable. Please download the IEDriverServer from    http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list and place the executable on your PATH.    (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

I have read the wiki on PATH but I'm still confused as to what this means for me. Where do I place the .exe in the scheme of my project?

wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

I am using selenium and cucumber to test a website

Here is my code

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'


@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the IE driver from the [downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list), then include the path to the file (example : C:\Users\megaxelize\Desktop)i.e. the location where you have downloaded the IEdriver, in your environment path.

This is the [way to update your env path vairable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Path specifies the directories in which executable programs are located on the machine that can be started without knowing and typing the whole path to the file on the command line.

More info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Answer (score 0):

You need IEDriverServer, which you can download from seleniumhq.org.Once your download is complete either you can mention the path to IEDriverServer.exe against your path variables (for which you need Admin access) or you can provide path to IEDriver.exe at command prompt using

java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=E:\selinum\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.32.3\IEDriverserver.exe

or U can set system property in your script if you use Java using :

```
File file = new File("E:\\selinum\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.31.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");//if    this is the location of your IEDriverServer.exe

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

- Download [IEDriverserver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
- Extract the zipped folders and add them in Environment Variables path.

  **My Computer > (right click) properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables**
- Click path under system variables and choose Edit.
- Paste the Driver location.

[image]

> @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie

or|

> @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :internet_explorer